# Qt Computing and Comparing Password Hashs

Tags: c++, qt, hash, cryptography

Currently building a web facing authentication service in Qt for a Quiz program.

It is my understanding that when storing a users password in a database it must be obscured in case it falls into the wrong hands.

The prevailing method appears to be a process of adding [Salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) to the password and then storing the computed hash of the combination.

This hash can later be compared :

HASH( userinput + SALT ) = StoredHash

Qt provides [QCryptographicHash](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html)::hash( data, Algorithm method) but as the key is presumably random I do not see how this can be useful.

Alternatively Qt Provides [QMessageAuthenticationCode](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessageauthenticationcode.html)::hash( message, key, Algorithm method) am I correct in thinking that message would be userpassword and key would be pseudo_random(row_id).

I am thinking of using the Sha2-256 Algorithim do I need [Cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) ?

Comment: *"but as the key is presumably random"* - `QCryptographicHash::hash` does not make use of a key.

Comment: Curiously, none of the algorithms provided by QCryptographicHash is recommended for cryptography usage.

Comment: @ddriver: [QCryptographicHash](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcryptographichash.html#Algorithm-enum) supports SHA-512, which is surely good enough cryptographic usage.

Comment: @TonyK I am not a cryptography expert, but I recall none of the SHA family is recommended. For example https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm recommends not to use SHA512 and SHA3 in particular.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Cryptographic hashes are not considered or called encryption. One reason why SHA-512 with a salt is not sufficient is a laptop (mine) can execute 750,000 per second, this would be applied to a list of 10,000,000 passwords sorted by frequency of usage Then there are special programs that fuzz those. Unless it is spear-fishing an attacker will probably be satisfied with 90% of the passwords cracked. So by lengthening the computer time from <2us to >100ms it takes the attacker 50,000 times as long, he will probably move on the the next site.

Comment: @ddriver: in your link, we can find: "Nevertheless, it is a good idea to use a more secure hash function like SHA256, SHA512, RipeMD, or WHIRLPOOL if possible." But we also find: "DO NOT use:
Fast cryptographic hash functions such as MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA512, RipeMD, WHIRLPOOL, SHA3, etc." Untangling this, I think it is fair to say that SHA512 is sufficient for cryptographic usage, but that a salted password hash should also be designed to run _slowly_, which can be achieved by requiring many calls to the underlying (cryptographically secure) hash algorithm.

Comment: @TonyK No matter how fast or slow the hash function it will be to fast, thus iteration is required. On my Laptop MD5 is only 5% faster than SHA256, based on that SHA512 is **not** sufficient for password security.

Comment: @zaph: Then we agree, don't we?

Comment: From the comments I draw a conclusion that the Qt functions are really only suitable for CRC.  I will investigate the suggested alternatives and post an possible answer for consideration. Thanking you all for your insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Qt Library components are indeed unsuitable for Cryptography.

[libSodiums implementation of Argon](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/password_hashing/the_argon2i_function.html) plugs in nicely and although relatively new [owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) and others are saying good things.

.pro

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -lsodium
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -lsodium
```

One must still [enforce](https://www.openhub.net/p/passwdqc) or [generate](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2016/07/new-wordlists-random-passphrases) strong passwords.

Comment: Hash is not Cryptography

Answer (score 0):

The commonly used algorithm for hashing password currently is bcrypt.

There is a simple C++ implementation [here](https://github.com/rg3/bcrypt)

There is two important thing for hashing password:

1. Salt, as you stated, to protect against rainbow table attack. Salt should be different for each user.
2. Iterative hashing, where you will hash the password several thousands of times to make brute force attack significantly slower.

bcrypt implement both of these.